# Use a font that distinguishes between "I" and "l"?

Tags: bug

When I saw the question [Exercises for pronouncing 'I'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/553/54), I thought it was asking about "L" (which native speakers of Japanese and Korean have difficulty with), rather than about "i".

Should we use a font that distinguishes between "l" and "I"?

I know that some fonts distinguish between the two, such as Comic Sans MS.

Comment: I hope the suggestion of Comic Sans is a joke.

Comment: @StoneyB I call it incentive ... for someone else to suggest a suitable font.

Comment: Well, there's not much point in thinking about it until we're approaching the end of Public Beta, when we get to design the site. Me, I prefer serif faces with lots of black and big visible points; but I can live with almost anything except Comic Sans or TNR.

Comment: @StoneyB when it's just a stylistic thing, it can wait, but something that affects usability should be dealt with earlier than that.

Comment: I'll take the incentive. Verdana. Plain and differentiating. I'll see about knocking up a script or some easy method of implementing it.

Comment: @Andrew  Verdana lacks most of the IPA characters required to represent English phonetically. Tahoma will work, and distinguishes the two characters.

Comment: Consider tagging this as `[bug]` to draw the attention of the SE developers, who'd have to implement this change.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't wait. Do it for yourself and let others know.**

Using a custom CSS for this site makes the trick.
You may write it manually (mine is for FF) and do whatever you want within, <s>even Comic Sans :)</s> Your browser will use it whenever the matching URL's are open.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://ell.stackexchange.com"), url-prefix("http://stackoverflow.com") {
  body {
   font-family:Tahoma !important;
  }
}
```

*Note:* Tahoma is Serif-type font, so `I` and `l` differ.

And/or download a browser plug-in to manage "skins":

- [Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome)
- [Stylish for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/stylish)

There are other plugins for this purpose, of course. Look up at SuperUser.

The good thing about plugins is that they let you access user-submitted CSS libraries. There are [many for StackExchange](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow). Not that I like them, but everyone has different taste.

[image: Style for SO]